# Не определяет True из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача вытащить имена у которых `True`,
есть список

```
Kovalev
True
Pupkin
False
Pechkin
False
Semenov
True
Kim
False
```

но условие не хочет мне показывать имена и `True`

код:

```
def parse_log():
    log = open("PATH_TO_FILE.txt",'r').read()
    array = log.split("\n")
    #print(array)
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            pass
        else:
            if array[i] == True:
                print(array[i])
                print(array[i-1])

parse_log()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас там список **строк**, поэтому вместо:

```
if array[i] == True:
```

Нужно:

```
if array[i] == "True":
```

---

Хотел предупредить, что переводы строк не обязательно только `'\n'`, могут быть и `'\r\n'`. Это зависит от платформы

Поэтому, советую делить на строки используя [str.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
array = log.splitlines()
```

Comment: так тоже не работает я пробовал до того как поставить `True`

Comment: @kombat, попробуйте так `array[i].rstrip()`. Кажется, я понял что у вас не так, обновил ответ

Comment: все заработало, спасибо огромное

Comment: @kombat, а вы использовали `.splitlines()` или `.rstrip()`? Советую использовать `.splitlines()`. И кст, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 2):

Раз список читается из файла, то его элементы - строки, и сравнивать нужно со строкой

```
if array[i] == "True":
```

Comment: так тоже не работает я пробовал до того как поставить `True`

Comment: Вы просто не проверили, что точно (строка с пробелом и т.д.) лежит в этом списке. Но вижу, что об этом уже сказали.